# What was Noach's relationship with Hashem/idols?

Tags: noach-noah-the-man

If Abraham was the first to recognise Hashem as the creator, what relationship did Noach then have with Him? More specifically: did Noach worship idols (the same which traditionally I believed Avraham was the first person in the world to renounce)?

Comment: I thought that Avraham was the first to come to a monotheistic belief by logic and without external proof. Noah heard God speak to him. The text doesn't indicate belief without that.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by a number of meforshim including Rav Hirsch. Noach received the knowledge of Hashem as being passed down from Adam Harishon and taught his children. The yeshivah of Shem VaEver was set up (as we learn that Yaakov went there) only for those who came on their own. Avraham determined that Hashem existed and had created the world on his own and also began to spread the knowledge to others in the world. That is what set him aside from Noach, who basically stood aside and arranged for his son and grandson to teach what he had learned to those who came and asked.

Comment: Aditionally, after the mabul, they was no more Ovde AZ. they come back afterward, and Avraham was born in a society which did not know Hashem